# Calculating numerical integral in Matlab using quad2d

Tags: matlab

I have a problem using `quad2d` in Matlab. The expression that is to be calculated is:

```
$\frac{8}{pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{sin(\frac{k*pi}{2}){k^2}e^-(k*pi)^2 sin(k*pi*x)$
```

I have written the following code:

```
fun = @(x,y) (8/(pi^2))*((sin(y.*pi/2))/(y.^2))*exp(-(((y.*pi)^2)*0.1))*sin(y.*pi*x.*1)

ca=quad2d(fun,0,1,1,200)
```

I would like to calculate the numerical integral of the expression above with two different variables. When I write this in Matlab, the error message I get is:

> Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision. 
>   There are a lot of error Messages. Does anyone have an idea to what should be done differently?

Comment: As you can see, StackOverflow does not support TeX equations. Please replace it with an image or remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is the inconsistent and partly wrong use of `*` and `.*`. You have to know that `quad2d` uses matrices or vectors for `x` and `y` to do the integration. To make it clear:

- `.*` denotes element-wise multiplication. Similarly, `./` and `.^` denote element-wise division or powers.
- `*` is a multiplication by a scalar if one argument is scalar (a number) and matrix multiplication if both inputs are vectors or matrices.

In your problem, as far as I see, you don't want any matrix multiplications. Thus, you will have to replace all `*`,`/`,`^` where two matrices (i.e., `x`,`y`) are involved by the element-wise operations. You can still use `*` etc. for multiplying matrices with scalars. I did exactly this here:

```
fun = @(x,y) (8/(pi^2))*((sin(y*pi/2))./(y.^2)).*exp(-(((y*pi).^2)*0.1)).*sin(pi*y.*x);
```

Note that `y*pi/2`, e.g., doesn't need dots, as `pi/2` is a scalar and `y` is a vector matrix. You *could* use `.*` there, both will work.

Now the integration works without errors:

```
ca=quad2d(fun,0,1,1,200)

ca = 
   0.0318
```